# Multidirectory makefile

Tags: gcc, makefile

Please tell me how to use the makefile to build the project consisting of the src folder and include. Project on the C.
I have three file in the src folder: main.c test.c foo.c and i have folder include with folder system where i Have file: test.h and foo.h
I would like to write in the main.c, for example, #include  where the system is in the folder include.

Please give an example makefile, since I find it hard to understand.
Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not given us much information, so I will have to guess. Suppose there are three files, `foo.c`, `bar.c` and `baz.c` in `src/`. And suppose your makefile is in the parent directory (which also contains `src/` and `include/`), and that you wish to build object files and the executable `foo` there. This should suffice:

```
VPATH = src
CFLAGS += -Iinclude

foo: foo.o bar.o baz.o
    $(CC) $^ -o $@
```

This is a crude makefile; much more sophisticated versions are possible, once you are comfortable with the basics.

**EDIT:**

We must learn to walk before we attempt to run. If you want to write a makefile that can handle complicated directory structures, you must understand simpler makefiles. Start with all files, both source files (`foo.c`) and header files (`foo.h`) in the same directory as the makefile. Then you can omit the first two lines of the makefile above. *Make sure you understand that makefile* before you create `src/` and need `VPATH = src`, then understand that before you introduce `include/` and `CFLAGS += -Iinclude`. If you try to skip these steps, you cannot succeed in more complicated cases.

Comment: I suggest adding `-Wall` to the `CFLAGS` line. And you might also add `-g`

Comment: Beta, thanx for the answer) But I do not quite understand, we CFLAGS specify when compiling and why there is a VPATH, if not difficult, you can more detail. I collect robot project. I have a folder src and a folder include, under include a folder system with file `radio.h` and the folder header with file `system.h`. I have a folder src with files `main.c`, `radio.c` and `system.c`. I want into file `main.c` write `#include <system/radio.h>` or `#include <header/system.h`, how it's making:D

Comment: I have read are documention makefile but i have not find (